# Error "tar: Invalid transform expression"while I am creating a TAR using system command in ruby. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I am creating a TAR using system command in ruby, passing a array as argument
which look likes this:

```
cmd_params = ["tar", "-cf", "my.tar", "wp-signup.php_1433243457_25152", "--transform='s/_[0-9]*_[0-9]*$//g'"]
system(*cmd_params)
```

But getting an Error

> tar: Invalid transform expression

is there any way out for doing this ??

Comment: Try removing the single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single quotes are needed on the command line or in a shell script to prevent the shell from interpreting the special characters. They're not needed here.

Comment: This fix is also true for the `exec` family of functions in C/C++